# Creating a room for a dungeon gives wrong dimensions/no walls

Tags: python, python-2.7, roguelike

I'm using Python 2.7 [libtcod](http://doryen.eptalys.net/libtcod/) to make a Roguelike, and currently trying to get a function to create an individual room based on a given floor number, x1, x2, y1, and y2 set of coordinates. The expected behavior is that I should get a room bounded with walls and otherwise filled with emptiness. For instance, makeRoom(0, 1, 1, 10, 10) should give:

```
----------
|********|
|********|
|********|
|********|
|********|
|********|
|********|
|********|
----------
```

Instead, however, I get a room that's as wide as the dungeon floor, respecting only the height, and the walls on the side never arrive. So instead, I get an arrangement more like this:

```
---------------------------
***************************
***************************
***************************
***************************
***************************
***************************
***************************
***************************
---------------------------
```

Changing the total available width of the dungeon floor causes the room to shrink or grow horizontally regardless of what size I ask it to have. The side walls never appear no matter how I tweak the ranges, where I tweak them, or what I comment or uncomment. In short, only the height and top/bottom is ever obeyed, no matter what I attempt.

base.py (main game loop):

```
import sys
import libtcodpy as libtcod
import entity
import dungeon

SCREEN_WIDTH = 80
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 50
LIMIT_FPS = 20

libtcod.console_set_custom_font('../dejavu10x10_gs_tc.png', libtcod.FONT_TYPE_GRAYSCALE | libtcod.FONT_LAYOUT_TCOD)
libtcod.console_init_root(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 'MadNet Zero', False)
libtcod.console_set_foreground_color(0, libtcod.white)

# The buggy functions
saturnSeven = dungeon.Dungeon(5)
saturnSeven.makeRoom(0, 1, 1, 10, 10)

player = entity.Player(25,25,3,4,0)
libtcod.console_print_left(0, player.X, player.Y, libtcod.BKGND_NONE, '@')
libtcod.console_flush()

while not libtcod.console_is_window_closed():
    libtcod.console_set_foreground_color(0, libtcod.white)
    #clear the player's old position
    libtcod.console_print_left(0, player.X, player.Y, libtcod.BKGND_NONE, ' ')

    #print terrain
    for y in range(len(saturnSeven.floor[player.Z][0])):
        for x in range(len(saturnSeven.floor[player.Z])):
            symbol = saturnSeven.getTerrainSymbol(x,y,player.Z)
            libtcod.console_print_left(0, x, y, libtcod.BKGND_NONE, symbol)
    libtcod.console_print_left(0, player.X, player.Y, libtcod.BKGND_NONE, player.char)
    libtcod.console_flush()
```

dungeon.py (does the meat of the work):

```
# Define terrain types as a pseudo-enum
wall, empty, solid = range(3)
class Cell(object):
    def __init__(self, terrain, items):
        self.terrain = terrain
        self.items = items
    def isPassable(self):
        if self.terrain != wall:
            return True
        else:
            return False

class Dungeon(object):
    def __init__(self, numfloors):
        self.MAXFLOORS = numfloors
        self.floor = [None]*numfloors
        for i in range(numfloors):
            self.floor[i] = makeFloor(20,20)

    def makeRoom(self, floorNum, Xmin, Ymin, Xmax, Ymax):
        #inner area
        for x in range(Xmin+1, Xmax):
            for y in range(Ymin+1, Ymax):
                self.floor[floorNum][x][y] = Cell(empty, None)
        #top/bottom wall
        for x in range(Xmin,Xmax+1):
            self.floor[floorNum][x][Ymin] = Cell(wall, None)
            self.floor[floorNum][x][Ymax] = Cell(wall, None)
        #left/right wall
        for y in range(Ymin, Ymax+1):
            self.floor[floorNum][Xmin][y] = Cell(wall, None)
            self.floor[floorNum][Xmax][y] = Cell(wall, None)

    def getTerrainSymbol(self, X, Y, Z):
        if self.floor[Z][X][Y] == None:
            return ' '
        if self.floor[Z][X][Y].terrain == wall:
            return '#'
        if self.floor[Z][X][Y].terrain == solid:
            return ' '
        if self.floor[Z][X][Y].terrain == empty:
            return '.'


def makeFloor(Xmax, Ymax):
    return [[Cell(solid, None)]*Xmax]*Ymax
```

I've eliminated the graphics as being a problem; the dungeon itself is definitely what's wrong, not how it's being displayed on screen. I can't find any reason the algorithm should be wrong in this way, though.

EDIT: The original version of the code that gave the diagram above had the "inner area" portion underneath the part that made the walls; putting it on top, as I did, results in the entire room being made up of walls, but still too wide. So far as I can tell they should give equivalent results; they do not.

Comment: Did you try to look at self.floor before and after each of the blocks that create the room?

Comment: I had the loop give me the coordinates where it should have been writing individual wall segments, and I've commented/uncommented each part of the function in turn to see the different results. Even if I narrow it down to one row, that row still winds up being as wide as it physically can, rather than as wide as it's set to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem (or at least one of them) is the definition of makeFloor.  Try this instead:

```
def makeFloor(Xmax, Ymax):
    return [[Cell(solid,None) for i in range(Xmax)]
            for j in range(Ymax)]
```

Explanation: If you do [x]*10, then you get a list containing 10 elements, each of which is x -- the *same* x.  If you change one, then the others will change as well.  Similarly, if you do [[x]]*10, then you get a list containing 10 sublists, each of which is the *same* sublist -- again, changing one will change them all.

Comment: This was it exactly: the room gets set exactly how it should with your definition. Thanks!